# How to see how good is my model?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit

I am using `glm` to find a model using training data and then use test data to see how well the model is behaving.  My response variable is `numeric`.

Below is a toy example that is showing the steps taken by me:

```
library(car)
summary(Prestige)
head(Prestige)
testidx <- which(1:nrow(Prestige)%%4==0)
prestige_train <- Prestige[-testidx,]
prestige_test <- Prestige[testidx,]

model <- glm(prestige~., data=prestige_train)
# Use the model to predict the output of test data 
prediction <- predict(model, newdata=prestige_test)
# Check for the correlation with actual result
cor(prediction, prestige_test$prestige)
```

My question is:

1. Other than `cor`, what other statistics (R functions) I can use to know the the goodness of fit?
2. How can I show this fit graphically in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root Mean Squared Error

The RMSE is the square root of the variance of the residuals. It indicates the absolute fit of the model to the data–how close the observed data points are to the model’s predicted values. Whereas estimators like $R^2$ is a relative measure of fit, RMSE is an absolute measure of fit. As the square root of a variance, RMSE can be interpreted as the standard deviation of the unexplained variance, and has the useful property of being in the same units as the response variable. Lower values of RMSE indicate better fit. RMSE is a good measure of how accurately the model predicts the response, and is the most important criterion for fit if the main purpose of the model is prediction.